# Google compute engine connecting to local UDP port

Tags: udp, google-compute-engine, ipc, firewall

I have a server listening on UDP port 22000 at a google compute engine.

I **can** connect from the **internet**, any machine no problem, but I **cannot connect from the local machine**.

The exact same code runs normally in any other (non-google) Linux machine.

My only changes to the default compute engine settings were to add a firewall rule allowing incoming UDP at port 22000.

Any help most welcome!

jaime

Comment: What IP address did you bind to? Are you using `0.0.0.0`, or the address of your network interface?

Comment: Not really bind but setsockname (as it's UDP). I've tried 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, "localhost" and the internal IP.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Apparently in these machines / kernel UDP sockets need to have a name (bind) before sending - never needed in other machines where I installed the server.

So in the sequence:

socket()
settimeout(..)
setsockname( .. )
socksendto( .. )
sockrecvfrom( .. )

... I've always avoided the "setsockname" as per the Lua socket documentation (http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/udp.html#setsockname):

> Note: This method can only be called before any datagram
>   is sent through the UDP object, and only once. Otherwise, the system
>   automatically binds the object to all local interfaces and chooses an
>   ephemeral port as soon as the first datagram is sent. After the local
>   address is set, either automatically by the system or explicitly by
>   setsockname, it cannot be changed.

... when sending was the first operation.

For some reason, here it is needed. To be specific, I've:

setsockname( '*', 0 ) - that is, bind to all local addresses, use an ephemereal port.